# Why don't planes drop their fuel tank during falling to avoid explosion?

Tags: planets, explosions, fire

Why fuel tanks of planes are not able to be integrated and disentegrated? If they were, planes could drop it during falling to avoid an explosion.

Or

Why don't planes empty their tanks just before falling.

Comment: If they're falling (not flying forwards) they'll drop the fuel tank then land in a big pile of burning fuel.

Comment: landing in a fire is better than explosion in itself, i think

Comment: If a plane "falls", the explosion is the least of your concerns, it happens after you crash. ;)

Comment: This belongs on [Aviation SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/), rather than Worldbuilding.

Comment: I just keep thinking *Plane crashes*, Pilot "We surived!" ... cue dumped fuel onto burning plane *boom*

Comment: Agreed, ask Aviation SE (and you'll find that in some cases, they do exactly what you say)

Comment: @Mr.Burns Stop thinking that and start reading [How is fuel dumping safe?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8147/753) on [aviation.se] for the facts.

Comment: In general, the answer to "why aren't airplanes designed with X / designed to do X?" for some arbitrary X is "cost versus benefit analysis", "failure modes" or a combination of the two. (In all fairness, failure modes should be a part of the cost analysis.) Suppose the tank detachment system accidentally engaged during a transatlantic cruise 10-12 km above the ground. As the pilot, now what do you do? Such a system will introduce weak points (bolts, perhaps cabling, conduits); how will those fare during heavy turbulence? And so on. Now consider how many accidents happen where this will help.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, Learn something new everyday. Films have also lied to me

Comment: The problem with most ideas like this is that with the number of flights in the air all the time, and the generally high reliability of airliners these days, and the types of accidents that are most common (during take-off and landing, not cruise), you need *absurd* reliability figures for it to not *cause* more accidents than where it helps. Even at something like 6-7 nines reliability (99.9999% to 99.99999%), a system that effectively downs the plane could very easily be more of a liability than an asset. Designing for that kind of reliability is **very, very, *very* hard.**

Answer (score 5):

This question is probably better suited for Aviation.SE, but until it can be migrated, these are my thoughts.

Airplanes usually store their fuel wherever they can, a substantial amount is usually stored in the wings. Dropping the fuel tanks would imply dropping the wings, which -- needless to say -- is not a great idea.

Some modern aircraft do dump fuel if they need to return for landing shortly after take off, but it's because they're too heavy, not to avoid an explosion, and they usually only dump enough to get below maximum landing weight. If they have the option to dump fuel, and it [seems likely the landing will result in an accident](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2856/2) they might chose to dump to the minimum necessary for landing, which is substantially more than empty.

I'm not an expert in the area of fuel dumping, but fuel is obviously required for flying, emptying the tanks would imply that you will have no power from the engines at all during your approach to emergency landing, which would rule out dumping *all* the fuel long before landing. Dumping fuel shortly before and during landing sounds to me like it would *increase* the risk of ignition rather than the other way around, and it's probably better to at least try to keep it contained. But I'm no expert on this, so someone else might want to correct me.

Comment: No of course they do not keep the fuel dump valve open **during** the crash/landing. They close the dump valve well before that.

Answer (score 0):

## They do dump / use up fuel before emergency landings

Wikipedia on [Fuel Dumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_dumping)

[image: Fuel dumping of an Airbus A340-600 above the Atlantic Ocean near Nova Scotia]

Fuel-dumping does happen. For airliners can be delieverd as a built-in function. If fuel-dumping is not available and the aircraft can stay aloft the pilots may elect to loiter near an airport while using up fuel. Once the pilots have reached a landing weight they are comfortable with they will (of course) cease dumping.

The reason is mainly to lighten the weight though because any "landing" that can result in an explosion is usually quite bad for the passengers. Dieing from fire after a crash can happen but it is relatively rare compared to severe trauma from the impact.

Comment: Fuel dumping is actually not as common as you seem to imply. A few models have it, others don't. And they most certainly won't *empty* their tanks.

Comment: `They do empty their tanks before emergency landings` this would be true only if corrected in the following manner: `They do empty their tanks before the emergency landings occurring when the tanks are full and the plane is above the maximum landing weight`

Comment: @falstro Edited to account for nit-picking readers, and for those that cannot figure out for themselves that they do not literally drain their tanks entirely empty.

Comment: @Federico That(!) depens on the situations. If braking is impaired they will want to lighten the load as much as they can.

Comment: See [Do airplanes dump fuel before landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29232/753) on [aviation.se].